# Installing Epson printer/ scanner

Tags: installation, drivers, printing, scanner

How can I install my Epson ME Office 535 All-in-one printer/scanner in Ubuntu 13.04?
.

Answer (score 1):

First, press `Super` KEY and search for `Printers`.

[image]

Then, click Add/Plus Icon

[image]

You will see this screen with your connected printer. Select your printer and click next. It will than ask you for a name and ETC ETC. Fill out. It will search the drivers for your printer. You should first search the internet and then from database.

Search in list EPSON
and then select model and apply