# Epson XP-215 not recognized by Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation

I recently bought a new printer Epson XP-215. I did a little research before buying it, to be certain that it was Linux compatible. I found the drivers on the manufacturers webpage and downloaded them. I was able to install the deb package (epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.3.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb) and installed the printer (via dash --> printing) and it is showing up in the list as "installed".
Then I connected the printer via USB to my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

```
~$ uname -a
Linux comutername 3.5.0-44-generic #67~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 16:16:57 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**already tried:**

- I'm certain that the usb port that I'm using is working, because it
  recognizes other devices instantly.
- I'm certain that my printer is    powered on!
- The printer is working, because I can print network    status reports
  and use it to copy documents.

When I try lsusb it doesn't show up in the list:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0424:2228 Standard Microsystems Corp. 9-in-2 Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:0403 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-0420 keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:4dfb Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Then I took a look in dmesg, where I can only find my mouse and keyboard (like with lsusb):

```
~$ dmesg | grep usb
[    0.233562] ACPI: bus type usb registered
[    0.233583] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.233593] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.233619] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.684044] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.684046] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.684049] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.684051] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.5.0-44-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.684053] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.5
[    1.744022] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.744024] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.744027] usb usb2: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.744029] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.5.0-44-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.744032] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.0
[    1.804018] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.804021] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.804023] usb usb3: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.804025] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.5.0-44-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.804027] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.1
[    1.864018] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.864021] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.864023] usb usb4: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.864025] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.5.0-44-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.864027] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.2
[    1.924017] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.924020] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.924022] usb usb5: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.924024] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 3.5.0-44-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.924027] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.3
[    1.984018] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.984020] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.984023] usb usb6: Product: OHCI Host Controller
[    1.984025] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 3.5.0-44-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.984028] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.4
[    1.984267] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    2.108105] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[    2.326234] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2228
[    2.326237] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.326239] usb 1-8: Product: Flash Card Reader
[    2.326241] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Generic
[    2.326243] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 000022272228
[    2.328538] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-8:1.0
[    2.328617] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.716020] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
[    2.898055] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=0403
[    2.898059] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.898061] usb 3-1: Product: USB Keyboard
[    2.898063] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Chicony
[    2.954155] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.954159] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.956856] input: Chicony USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input2
[    2.956996] hid-generic 0003:04F2:0403.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Chicony USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:13.1-1/input0
[    2.964124] input: Chicony USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/input/input3
[    2.964258] hid-generic 0003:04F2:0403.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Chicony USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:13.1-1/input1
[    3.164024] usb 3-2: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ohci_hcd
[    3.329056] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=4dfb
[    3.329061] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.329064] usb 3-2: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    3.336378] input: USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input4
[    3.336490] hid-generic 0003:0461:4DFB.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.1-2/input0
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: How did you know it working ? I mean that it somehow print with ubuntu ? or you tested with other machine ?

Comment: @DuminduMahawela Well I got 1 vista laptop from my gf, I'm gonna try to connect the printer via usb to it to see if it's recognized by it. I got a bussy day and will try it asap. I'll let you know.

Comment: I tried to automatically connect the printer to my b-box 3 router (vdsl), using the WPS button on the router and the wifi button on the printer. This always failed and it's impossible to fill in a WPS pin in the router, as there is no option to do that. Today I managed to install the software on my gf's windohs vista and this automatically configured the network settings for the printer. Then I got back on my Ubuntu and in the printing program the printer was automatically detected under network printers. From that moment on the installation worked like a charm, I printed a testpage. It works!

Comment: If you don't have a Windows distribution at hand, [you might solve your problem this way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/659298/epson-scanner-no-longer-recognised/718258#718258).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **The Problem:**

I needed to be able to connect my newly bought Epson XP-215 all-in-one device to the local network and it had to work flawlessly with my Ubuntu 12.04 OS.

First I thought I could do it trying to connect it via usb, but it didn't get recognized. Epson doesn't provide any software packages for Linux to configure the printer on the local network, not automatically nor manually.

## **Solution:**

So the only solution I found was using the only Windohws pc I had. I installed the software that came along with the printer onto that pc and ran through the wizard until the printer was automatically configured into the wireless network. Once that was succeeded, install the appropriate deb package from the Epson website (Epson does provide the **drivers** for Linux!). **You will need to download them from the Epson website**, because they don't come standard in Ubuntu 12.04. In my case I took the 64-bit version.

Once you installed the appropriate deb package for your Ubuntu 12.04, when you go to your dash and type in printing and open the program. You click on **Add** and click on **network printer**. Make sure your **printer is powered on**! And **wait for about 30 seconds**. It should get listed automatically. **Select your printer** and then click **forward**, it should automatically start searching for the appropriate driver from your newly added drivers. In the next screen you can modify the printer name if you like or keep it like it is and click on **apply**.

Your printer should now be fully functional. Try to print a test page to see if it works.

When you open dash again, type scan and open the program "simple scan". Place your printed test page on the scanner and click scan. It should start scanning your test page and voilà!

Comment: If you don't have a Windows distribution at hand, [you might solve your problem this way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/659298/epson-scanner-no-longer-recognised/718258#718258).

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded driver from website may not compatible with 12.04. Try with the Epson Inkjet ESC driver which is in [Main Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=printer-driver-escpr) :

```
sudo apt-get intall printer-driver-escpr
```

You can use [Mtink](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&section=all&arch=any&keywords=mtink&searchon=names) for printer maintenance:

```
sudo apt-get install mtink mtink-doc
```

Comment: I want to thank you sincerely for looking for a solution. The drivers that I downloaded from the Epson website in the deb package, managed to add the latest new Epson printer drivers to my driver repository on my pc. The problem was apparently that Epson doesn't provide a software package for Linux to be able to configure the printer and put it on the network. Thanks again for helping me!

Comment: refer these Questions [1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303642/installing-epson-printer-scanner), [2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303982/installing-printer-from-local-network), [3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154470/setting-up-a-network-printer), [4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229872/how-do-i-add-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: I posted an answer to your 1 (first link), as it is the same brand of printer as I have and the solution should be more or less the exact same thing. I don't know if it will be for the other brands like HP and Cannon, as I'm not yet familiar with them if it comes to providing Linux drivers. Kind regards!