# Epson scanner no longer recognised

Tags: 15.04, scanner, epson

I have Lubuntu 15.04 on Dell E6410, Epson printer xp-310 all in one series. The printer is working fine after finding downloading the drivers. I was using the scanner by opening simple scan, but yesterday I got the message "no scanner detected". Fearing the worst, all connections were checked and the printer itself still doesn't miss a beat and works as well as always.

Any clues that can be thrown to me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep iscan` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: Can you say what iscan is ?

Comment: `iscan` is the Epson scanner driver.

Comment: BTW @Brian, to see whether xsane is functional on your machine and can detect your scanner, connect your scanner (by USB I imagine) type `scanimage -L` from terminal. Report whether your scanner is detected. Tell us whether you are connecting from USB2 or USB3.

Answer (score 2):

I have an all-in-one Epson XP-215 device and when I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.04, I had the same problem as you.

You didn't mention if you use a print server or if your scanner is directly connected to the network.
In my case, the device is attached directly to the network.

When I performed `dpkg-l | grep iscan` it showed me:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep iscan

    rc  iscan                                                2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7                      amd64        simple, easy to use scanner utility for EPSON scanners
    rc  iscan-data                                           1.36.0-1                                   all          Image Scan! for Linux data files
    rc  iscan-network-nt                                     1.1.1-1                                    amd64        Image Scan! Network Plugin
```

The `rc` in front of `iscan*` means:

- `r`: the package was marked for removal
- `c`: the configuration files are currently present in the system

So I had to purge the `iscan` software packages to be able to correctly reinstall all 3 packages.

```
sudo dpkg -P iscan*
```

Afterwards, I went to the [Epson download site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) and downloaded the correct scanner driver for my distribution (mine is 64-bit), `iscan-bundle-x.x.x.x64.deb.tar.gz`.

You extract the `*.deb` file to where you want. Move inside the created directory and launch the installer using:

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Once that is done and you perform `dpkg -l | grep iscan` again, you should see the `ii` flags in front of the packages (which means the package is installed correctly):

```
ii  iscan                                                2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7                      amd64        simple, easy to use scanner utility for EPSON scanners
ii  iscan-data                                           1.36.0-1                                   all          Image Scan! for Linux data files
ii  iscan-network-nt                                     1.1.1-1                                    amd64        Image Scan! Network Plugin
```

So far so good! But the scanner function still won't work.

Next, you need to modify `epkowa.conf` with superuser privileges:

```
sudo vim /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf
```

In `vim` type `:set nu` to activate the line numbering on your screen.
Now scroll down to line 56 and press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key or <kbd>i</kbd> key on your keyboard. This makes you able to type text.
Copy/paste the line below:

```
net autodiscovery
```

The `autodiscovery` option will automatically discover your scanner's IP address on the network. In case the IP would change one day, this option will keep working.

Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on your keyboard to exit insert-mode and type `:wq!` to save and exit the file.

And voilà, go back to simple scan and your scanner should be recognized again!

Enjoy your scanning!

Comment: Thank you for the tip.
The scanner was working till now, March 2023.
I tried the `net autodiscovery` solution, but it didn't work. Then I tried adding `net 192.168.xx.xxx` (my device's IP) and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the problem I had, When I was using simple scan, it was saying No Scanner Detected. I then remembered I enabled the Firewall. So I turned it off and hay presto It now works, so I told firewall to allow that IP or Port now working. Maybe help you?

Answer (score 0):

I have an all in one EPSON L210, everything was fine with ubuntu 15.04 but when updating to 15.10 or 16.04 nothing works. I follow exactly as Epson indicate here [epson_instructions](http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html#sec6-1) but nothing works, then looking for solutions I installed the xSane image scanning program.

1. Looking solutions for this program I found out that our USER must be included at the SCANNER groups (I did it installing USER AND GROUPS) and we must change RUN=no to RUN=yes inside etc/deafult/saned.
2. Then I checked the usb with lsusb and it says **Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04b8:08a1 Seiko Epson Corp.** So I open the **/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules** but it was included. SO WHAT IS WRONG?
3. So at the end and reading, again, the `epkowa.conf` it says: which has a product ID of 0x0110, would look as follows:

> ```
> #
> #usb 0x04b8 0x0110 with 0x not only 04b8 at libsane.rules
> ```

So as anything was working, I changed the ID at `40-libsane.rules` adding the `0x`. And it works.